# iCal-like calendars jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Does anyone know a calendar that has a big size  as in the link : http://www.htmldrive.net/items/demo/568/astonishing-iCal-like-calendars-with-jQuery

Because I don't want  build a calendar like this demo, I just want to use it.
I tried to use other calendars as JScal but it is small.

Thank you

Comment: What is wrong with just using the source of that calendar in the question?

Comment: What are you targeting, desktop or mobile website? Are you looking for a calendar with liquid layout?

Comment: For desktop, it will be appreciated withe liquid layout! thx

Answer (score 2):

What exactly is your UI requirement? For example, I'd consider the following calendar "big":

- http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/

And you can probably customize the layout to fit your needs. If you require more than that, you should "refine" your requirements :)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using JQuery then you can use following code to increase size

```
${'div.ui-datepicker').css({ font-size:10px; });
```

here 'div.ui-datepicker' is datepicker instance, you need to change it according to your code.